# What is the purpose of putting form elements inside DIVs?

Tags: html, css

I'm reading through an HTML file right now and I noticed that the form elements inside one of its forms are placed inside a DIV.

For example.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
    <div>
    <label for="author">Name: <em class="required">(Required)</em></label>
    <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
    <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I observed that it's perfectly fine to not place them inside the DIVs anyway.

What is the purpose of this?

PS: There was no styling involved in the CSS that target the DIVs, all the styles were specifically targeted for "labels", "inputs" and so on. But none that target the DIVs.

Honestly, the only effect it has on the layout is some tiny padding which can also be set by specifying a special class for the elements, that's all.

And if it's for styling, there's no associated styles set for it anyway, so why put it in the first place?

Can anybody crack the reasoning behind this?

Here's the entire document.

```
body {
    font: 62.5%/1 "Myriad Pro", Frutiger, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;
}

form {
  font-size: 1.4em;
    width: 30em;
}


/* fieldset styling */
fieldset {
    margin: 1em 0; /*  space out the fieldsets a little*/
    padding: 1em;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
}

/* legend styling */
legend {
    font-weight: bold;
}

form div {
    padding: 0.4em 0;
}


/* style for  labels */
label {
    display: block;
}

/* style for required labels */
label .required {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color:#760000;
}

input {
  width: 20em;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
}

input.radio, input.submit {
  width: auto;
}

#remember-me .radio {
    margin-right: 1em;
}

/* style form elements on focus */
input[type="text"]:focus, textarea:focus {
    background: #ffc;
}

-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<form id="comments_form" action="#" method="post">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Your Contact Details</legend>
    <div>
    <label for="author">Name: <em class="required">(Required)</em></label>
    <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div>
    <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
    <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Comments</legend>
    <div>
    <label for="text">Message: <em class="required">(Required)</em></label>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="remember-me">
    <legend>Remember Me</legend>
        <div>
        <label for="remember-yes"><input id="remember-yes" class="radio" name="remember" type="radio" value="yes" />Yes</label>
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for="remember-no"><input id="remember-no" class="radio" name="remember" type="radio" value="no" checked="checked" />No</label>
        </div>

</fieldset>

<div>
<input id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" type="submit"/>
</div>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To make the form more flexible to move or to do any changes for the whole form..

Comment: Is this a quiz? What's the point of asking about what someone else did? From the question I understand this is not an issue you are dealing with a site you are developing.

Comment: @TsahiAsher It is a question that pertains the reasoning and purpose of the way the code is structured. As an aspiring developer, we don't necessarily create elements without purpose, and that is what I'm trying to uncover-with your help and the others-right now.

Answer (score 3):

Besides styling, it also depends on **doctype** of the markup. For example, with **XHTML 1.0 Strict**, form elements like `<label>`, `<input>` must be wrapped in block-level elements, otherwise it can't pass the [**W3C Markup Validation Service**](http://validator.w3.org/). However, some other doctypes allow such markup.

Years ago it's a fashion to have a **W3C validate** banner on your site. Because of that fashion, many people overreact about validation. Like in this example, wrapping with `fieldset` is valid but people may still go with `div` or `p`, just like people avoid using `table` even if presenting tabular data. If you are reviewing some legacy codes, this might be a possible reason.

Comment: The code in the question is valid XHTML 1.0 Strict even if the `div` markup is removed. The `fieldset` element is block-level.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela What i want to say is, because of that fashion, many people overreact about validation. Like in this example, wrapping with fieldset is valid but people may still go with div or p tags, just like people avoid using table even if presenting tabular data.

Answer (score 3):

In the given case, the `div` markup causes each label/input pair to appear on a line of its own, which is generally a good idea. There are many alternative ways to achieve that, but this is one of the simplest and also useful for styling that you might want to add later.

Moreover, in this case there *is* a style sheet rule that uses the markup: the selector `form div` matches these `div` element, and the rule for it sets 0.4em padding above and below the content of each `div`.

Answer (score 2):

the purpose is usually for styling. For example, say you wanted the label to sit above the input like the below example. And you wanted a copy of the same thing just to the right:

```
Label Here      Label Here
Input Here      Input Here
```

it would be very difficult to accomplish this with the following

```
<label for="author">Name: <em class="required">(Required)</em></label>
<input name="author" id="author" type="text" />

<label for="author">Name: <em class="required">(Required)</em></label>
<input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
```

Now add in `div`s and you can float the `div`s instead (as well as add other CSS like `margin` to separate the two columns):

```
<div> <-----Add styles to parent
  <label for="author">Name: <em class="required">(Required)</em></label>
  <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
</div>

<div> <-----Add styles to parent
  <label for="author">Name: <em class="required">(Required)</em></label>
  <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I saw your update, it could also be to clear each "row" since `label`s and `input`s are `inline` by default. Check out the difference in the fiddle:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7v77ov6k/1/)

It could be that the developer believes it to be more semantic with `div`s, it could be to set things up for later incase the layout changes and they want to add CSS like the above example, it could be he/she doesn't really know what they're doing. It could be a number of things

Comment: But the developer does none of that. 

Instead, what he does is nearly similar as,

LABEL
INPUT

But he sets the "display" of the label into block.

Comment: I'll just go ahead and assume that the developer put it this way for "semantic" and "future" reasons.

Answer (score 1):

@Johnsy Omniscient : yes some times developers will add additional  tags to update the site for future technology. when responsive design was new; we added extra divs, etc to help the transformation when going mobile etc